# Can I use intel's TBB with gcc?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Can I use intel's TBB with gcc? And if not, what would be the equivalent so I could use it while compiling with gcc?
I don't think I can but is always better to ask.

Comment: You certainly can use TBB with the GNU compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, this is what their [documentation](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/wiki/index.php?title=Using_TBB) has to say:

> Do I have to use Intel’s compilers? No. You should be able to use any
>   ISO compliant C++ compiler. We have tested it very well on the gnu
>   (gcc) compiler, Intel’s C++ compiler, Microsoft’s compiler, and
>   Apple’s gnu compiler. We have also built with success on a variety of
>   other compilers. Check the web site for update on experiences with
>   different systems and compilers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from the [FAQ](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/wiki/index.php?title=General_Questions_about_TBB#What_compilers.2C_operating_systems_and_processors_are_supported.3F).

> The project is dedicated to supporting all compilers, all OSes and all
>   processors as a cornerstone objective of the project.